# rectangle for detection object with HOG+SVM Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use rectangle for object detection, but firstly I want to understand the code.This is a sample code :

```
vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
    size_t i, j;

    hog.detectMultiScale(mGray, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);


    for( i = 0; i < found.size(); i++ )
        {
            Rect r = found[i];
            for( j = 0; j < found.size(); j++ )
                if( j != i && (r & found[j]) == r)
                    break;
            if( j == found.size() )
                found_filtered.push_back(r);
        }



    if(found.size()) {
            Rect r = found[0];
            r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
            r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
            r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.07);
            r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.8);
            LOGD("c : %d, r : %d",r.height,r.width);



         rectangle(mGray, r.tl(), r.br(), cv::Scalar(255,0,0), 3);
    }
```

So, I want to understand this code line by line :

```
if(found.size()) {
                Rect r = found[0];
                r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
                r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
                r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.07);
                r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.8);
                LOGD("c : %d, r : %d",r.height,r.width);
```

what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's made to shrink object rectangle as follows (red - original detection, green - new rectangle):

[image]

```
r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1); // move rectangle to right by 10% of width
r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8); // reduce rectangle width
r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.07); // move rectangle down by 7% of width
r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.8); // reduce rectangle width
LOGD("c : %d, r : %d",r.height,r.width); // print coordinates of top left corner, width and height
```

I think it was made because when you train detector, you pass samples with some background around object. So when you detect object with such detector, rectangle will be quite bigger than object. In order to make rectangle more specific you may shrink it as described above.

Comment: why to reduce rectangle width and height @akarsakov ? what's that image link ?

Comment: In order to make rectangle size closer to object, since detector will output rectangle with some background around object. Image is provided to illustrate this process.

Comment: Do you think that code will be completely work for me @akarsakov ? Can you give me a link for illustrate this process ? that link not found

Comment: @FranksyeSipangkar You should make experiment. If size of rectangle is good enough for you, use it as is. Otherwise, just remove this lines of code (from `r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);`).

Comment: thanks for your advice.that's work for me.I have a question for you, do you know about accuration rate of  custom object detection using HOG+SVM ? @akarsakov

Comment: @FranksyeSipangkar, it's very broad question. Are you interesting in how to calculate accuracy rate? BTW, if this answer is work for you please consider to mark it correspondingly.